# External harddrive not recognized when plugging in directly, but recognized when plugging in via an USB C hub

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have an external harddrive (an old model of Seagate Backup Plus Desktop Drive that requires external power source), and it used to work fine for a few years. Recently, I tried to plugged the drive using the provided USB A 3.0 cable into an USB A port on my computer, but the computer can't recognize it. I tried a different computer, and it doesn't work either.

Here are some details

- I can hear the drive spinning up once it is plugged into the computer like before
- On Windows, the disk management utility doesn't show anything after plugging in the cable. The `device manager` does not refresh when it is plugged in as well.
- On Linux, `fdisk -l` doesn't show additional disks when plugged in. `lsusb` output doesn't change when plugged in.

When I was about to make the conclusion that the disk is dead, I found my Macbook pro recognizes the disk when it is plugged in. Since my Macbook pro does not have USB A port, I plugged it in using an USB C hub. On my other windows laptop that has both USB A port and USB C port, the drive get recognized when plugging in using the same USB C hub to the USB C port, and it cannot be recognized when plugging in using the USB A port directly (same symptom as described above).

To summarize, the drive can be recognized when plugged in using the USB C hub, but not when plugged in directly to USB A port. I am not sure why this happens. Any suggestions are appreciated.

An USB C hub is a device that allow other type of connections (USB A, Ethernet, HDMI, etc.) using USB C.

Comment: Did you try another cable?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I tried this cable on other external drive that is known to be working, and they worked. I also tried other good cables on this drive and got the exact same result.

Comment: My gut feeling is it's not getting enough power from the USB-A.  Try a Y-split dual USB-A or other means to supply extra power, there are in-line power options as well as hubs like QGeeM's, or just stick with Type-C?

Comment: @Arctiic That's interesting, Unfortunately, I don't own such Y-split cable for USB 3.0, but I will try to get one if that can fix the problem. The external harddrive does have its own  power supply (a 12VDC wall adapter), so it should received enough power even if it can't draw much from the USB port. The USB C hub I am using is a passive one that does not connects to external power. However, I won't be surprised if it can draw more power from the computer than USB A.

Comment: If power is **not** the issue, I would take a look pre-boot (from BIOS/UEFI) and see if it pops up there.  Depending on mobo, I know some have USB settings for each port, maybe there's a compatibility issue and you need to set a port to legacy mode?